# Showing the isomorphisms between two relative homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have been given that

> $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed subset. Then the groups $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-A )$ and $H_{i+1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-(A \times \{0\}) )$ are isomorphic

Using this I am supposed to show that the following

> If $A$ and $B$ are closed homeomorphic subsets of $R^{n}$, then $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-A )$ and $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-B )$ are isomorphic.

Note: I know that for closed homeomorphic subsets $A$ and $B$ , we have $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-A ) \cong H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-B )$. But I am not supposed to use that. I am going to prove $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-A ) \cong H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-B )$ using the problem above, using long exact sequence for pairs.

I wonder what is the main motive to move to higher dimension? I think we will be able to find open sets to use excision. I tried applying excision, but looks like I am not able to get the required subspaces.

Now how else can I attempt this problem?

Comment: Where does this come from? Exercise in a textbook? And which methods did you use to prove that for closed homeomorphic subsets $A$ and $B$, one has $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-A ) \cong H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-B )$?

Comment: @PaulFrost, I don't know the reference. I am supposed to prove $H(\mathbb{R}^n-A) \cong \mathbb{R}^n-B)$ using the statements mentioned above. I figured out that using long exact sequence for pairs and $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-A )$ and $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-B )$ will be sufficent, but I am unable to show  $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-A )$ and $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-B )$

Comment: @PaulFrost, I have not yet proved $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-A ) \cong H_i(\mathbb{R}^n-B )$. I just read on MSE that it holds. It uses Alexander's Duality. I am not supposed to use that. I was asked to prove the statement mentioned above in this comment using the problem that I have posted.